# How do I change variable values in Google Apps Script debugger

Tags: debugging, google-apps-script

Back in the day when I used debuggers for Fortran and C, I could change variables while in the debugger.  Is it possible to do this in the GAS debugger?  Google did not return examples of it for me.  Thanks

Comment: Suggest how I can change a variable within the debugger and I will.

Comment: @Cooper do you know how to do this? If so can you please tell us. I have also tried and do not know how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

As of my today 13/09/2023, **Google Apps Script's built-in debugger does not natively support changing variable values on-the-fly during a debugging session.** This is a limitation of the Google Apps Script platform.

However, if you're trying to test different scenarios or troubleshoot issues, you can use a few workarounds:

1. **Manual Variable Change**:

   - Before starting the debugger, manually change the variable's value in the script editor.
   - Run the script with the debugger to see how it behaves with the new value.
2. **Conditional Logic**:

   - Use conditional logic in your script to set variable values based on certain conditions. This way, you can control the flow of your script and the values of variables during debugging.
3. **Logging**:

   - Use the `Logger.log()` function to log variable values at different points in your script. This can help you understand the flow of data and how variables change over time.
4. **External Tools**:

   - Consider using external tools or platforms that might offer more advanced debugging capabilities. For instance, if you're working with Google Sheets, you might use the Chrome Developer Tools to debug client-side scripts.
5. **Feedback to Google**:

   - Google continuously updates its products based on user feedback. If you find this feature essential, consider providing feedback directly to Google. They might consider adding this feature in future updates.